# How to construct a complex LEFT JOIN with aliasing using sea-query in Rust?

Tags: sea-orm, sea-query

I'm working on a Rust project where I use `sea-query` to build SQL queries. I have the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tblcomponent AS com1 
LEFT JOIN tblcomponent AS com2 ON com1.intParentComponentId_fk=com2.intId_pk 
LEFT JOIN tblcomponent AS com3 ON com2.intParentComponentId_fk=com3.intId_pk 
LEFT JOIN tblcomponent AS com4 ON com3.intParentComponentId_fk=com4.intId_pk 
LEFT JOIN tblcomponentdef AS comdef2 ON com2.intComponentDefId_fk=comdef2.intId_pk
LEFT JOIN tblcomponentdef AS comdef3 ON com3.intComponentDefId_fk=comdef3.intId_pk
LEFT JOIN tblcomponentdef AS comdef4 ON com4.intComponentDefId_fk=comdef4.intId_pk
```

The main challenge I'm facing is to set up multiple `LEFT JOIN` clauses using the same table (`tblcomponent`) with different aliases (`com1`, `com2`, `com3`, `com4`).

Does anyone know how to replicate the above SQL using `sea-query` in Rust?

As you can see it is a nested self-join. That is why we need multiple aliases.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is kinda how it looks like

```rust
use entities::{tblcomponent,tblcomponentdef}
tblcomponent::Entity::find()
        .join(
            JoinType::LeftJoin,
            //???
todo!()
        )
```